# Easier way to check if multiple variables do not equal to a value php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, if-statement, foreach

I have a lot of variables in which I want to make sure they do not equal a certain value.

```
if($post[0] !== "-" && $post[3] !== "-" && $post[8] !== "-" ...) {
    // code to be executed
}
```

A function seems to be the smartest solution, something on the lines of:

```
function check_var($junk_value, $array) {
    foreach($array as $arr) {
        if($arr[$key]) == $junk_value) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
$junk_value = "-";
$array = array($post[0], $post[3], $post[8], $hello);
check_var($junk_value, $array);
```

I'm not very good with foreach loops and I don't know how everyone else uses "$key" but it's outputting that it was not set for me. I've always wondering how people used the "$key" and "$value" variables without ever defining them.

EDIT: I soaked up so much information on this question. In 10 minutes, I feel like I know so much more. Thank you to all the answers.

Comment: Your loop will only ever test the first `$key`.  Get rid of your `else` clause and move your `return true` outside of the `foreach` or just remove it entirely, since an ending function returns true by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (!in_array('-', $post)) {
  // code to be executed
}
```

And your code should be

```
function check_var($junk_value, $array) {
  foreach($array as $val) {
    if ($val == $junk_value) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: ahhh this logic. always something easier and always a better way to do thing. I'm going to use your answer, but do you know why my function doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question of

> I've always wondering how people used the "$key" and "$value"
>   variables without ever defining them

You reference the key in the foreach declaration:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
```

Comment: thank you, that answers my question. does the $key have a special meaning in a foreach loop?

Comment: Yes so if you have an array like `array('foo'=>'bar', 'baz'=>'bat')`, the `$key` would be foo and baz. In your example of a `$_POST` array, the `$key` would be the input field name. If you omit associative keys, like `array('foo', 'bar')`, the `$key`s would be 0 and 1, respectively.

Comment: thank you, that clears things up. and it was meant to be $post :)

Answer (score 1):

when using

```
foreach($array as $arr)
```

here `$arr` is the **value** and **not the key** so you need to check

```
 if($arr == $junk_value)
```

In case you also want key then use

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
```

but then again using foreach you are having both  `value` and `key` so no need of using `$arr[$key]`